# How to buffer a point by cardinal distances to create a polygon?

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.0, mapinfo

I am trying to buffer a point by distances in a table to create a polygon or line for example

For a point with known x,y

buffer based on the following radius:
North= 20m
East= 21.5m
South= 14m
West= 26m

Despite trying I haven't been successful does anyone know if this is possible?

---

Yes am trying to create a circle type shape from the four cardinal points.

[image]

Comment: Are these the corners of the polygon, or are you connecting these points using arcs?

Comment: In case of arcs, it can be done manually in AutoCAD, if you have just a few points.

Comment: Sorry I wasnt able to do this QGIS came up with an error as shown? I have tried a few different ways. I should have said I am trying to make a circular shape out of this the method would probably work. Thanks James

Comment: Can you post a link to an illustration of what you're trying to do? It is rather confusing right now. Are you trying to create a best circle from the four points?

Comment: Are you trying to do something like [this](https://pp.userapi.com/c411322/u17020874/l_d91ae31a.png)? Dispersion of pollutant?

Comment: @Nadya - Thats exactly what I am trying to do. Thanks for everyones help regards James

Comment: Related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188139/buffering-point-with-different-distance-toward-n-e-s-w-using-arcgis-for-deskt

Answer (score 3):

Not the most elegant solution, but you could use a spreadsheet to calculate WKT (Well-Known Text) descriptions of your vertices, then import them as a geographic shape. For example, in Excel or OpenOffice, create a set of columns with the centre point coordinates (x and y) and the N/S/E/W distances you mention:

```
Point    x    y    N    S    E    W
Alpha    100  155  20   14   21.5 26
```

[image]

Then, make a column called WKT and use an equation to build the WKT string:

```
="POLYGON(("&B2&" "&(C2+D2)&", "&(B2+F2)&" "&C2&", "&B2&" "&(C2-E2)&", "&(B2-G2)&" "&C2&", "&B2&" "&(C2+D2)&"))"
```

Save as a **tab-delimited** text file, then use the "Delimited text" plugin to import the text file. The plugin should recognise the WKT field, and add the geometry as a layer.

[image]

Comment: @user12309, I now see (from the added comment) you're looking for a **circular** shape, so this won't help.

Comment: This is an example of what I am trying to do. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/36153074/GIS%20query.jpg

Comment: You can smooth edges of polygon using Peak algorithm in arcgis but that needed advanced licence. But you can search similar functionality in qgis.