# Variable distance per direction buffer

Tags: gdal, r, buffer

Just as a thought idea.
I was thinking of creating a cell reception model using a cell towers point layer.
I want to create some sort of buffer radiating from each point but depending in other layers (buildings, surface roughness, etc..) I want the buffer to be longer or shorter in a specific direction.
Has anyone tried this?
Seen anything like this?
I am used to working with **R** and prefer creating such a tool with code and not a model in ArcGIS/QGIS if thats an issue.

## Edit

so after being flagged as too broad, what i figure iam looking for is a way to create a *buffer* with a different width in every angle.

The point is being able to use some sort of formula (surface roughness, signal strength and so on..) to define the buffer's width in each angle.

Comment: I have seen cell tower coverage models in ArcGIS that are based on clipping a digital elevation model (DEM) using a buffer around the tower location (based on the range of the tower), then calculating a viewshed within a wedge-shaped section radiating from the tower (modeling for each individual antenna, which does not cover 360 degrees). A viewshed is not a perfect way to model reception, since it does not model signal bouncing. I don't know much about R, but a viewshed is a common gis operation.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour], which explains how our Focused Q&A model operates. Questions which ask multiple questions  or which try to solicit multiple opinions or start a discussion are likely to be placed on hold. If you try to implement this idea and it doesn't work, then it would be appropriate to ask for help here, but problem-solving a thought experiment isn't really on-charter.

Comment: Could you use an elliptical buffer? Or some other radial shape with a varying radius? Plenty of functional forms that create directional shapes.

Comment: Python code for variable buffer. https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188139/buffering-point-with-different-distance-toward-n-e-s-w-using-arcgis-for-deskt

Comment: Tks for editing your question. Unfortunately, we don't have an option in the system to switch the close reason. Now, your question lacks a reproducible example (code snippet). See here, though what to do: https://gis.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4006/tweaking-custom-close-reason-for-poorly-framed-code-debugging-writing-improving.