# Create a polygon around a point with interpolated distances from point in ArcGIS using Python

Tags: arcpy, python, numpy

I have a shapefile of points with 16 fields associated with each point - these four fields are Q1, Q2, Q3, and Q4 (quadrants). Each quadrant field contains a value that represents a distance from each point in nautical miles.

For example I have a lat/lon point with values:
Q1 = 10,
Q2 = 20,
Q3 = 30,
Q4 = 20,

So one point, with 4 rays (one in each quadrant) a Q# distance away from the point, and I want to calculate a round-ish polygon around the point based on these 4 distances.

I need to do this programmatically hopefully using arcpy, numpy, or some other python module.

I was thinking to use the degree-distance tool on arcmap, but I beleive that can only be done by "point and click" and not by an arcpy tool.

[image: Black center point is my point, with the four blue rays extending in each quadrant a distance away from the point, and I want to compute a round-ish polygon connecting these 4 rays]

Comment: Radius itself is usually not enough to find the coordinates of a point, so unless you're assuming 45°, a roundish polygon sounds challenging.  If you just want a radius per quadrant, this post has some interesting code.  https://community.esri.com/thread/187645-is-it-possible-to-make-a-buffer-that-has-four-quadrants-with-different-radii

Comment: Here's a similar answer assuming the distance is along the axes.  You could plug in sin/cos of some angles if desired.  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188139/buffering-point-with-different-distance-toward-n-e-s-w-using-arcgis-for-deskt