# Generate irregular 3d Buffer of polyline

Tags: arcpy, python, arcgis-pro

I have a 3D polyline That i would like to 3D buffer 300 Feet XY and 100 Feet in the Z direction. I think it may be something similar to this but in 3 dimensions rather than 2 ([Buffering point with different distance toward N, E, S, W using ArcGIS for Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188139/buffering-point-with-different-distance-toward-n-e-s-w-using-arcgis-for-deskt)) This is buffering a point, whereas i am attempting to on a line. but the process could be similar, i suppose.

I would prefer a python approach, but ArcGIS would work as well, i suppose. I am going to have a couple hundred thousand of these lines to calculate similar to this one.

My end goal is to measure the amount of overlap that these irregular buffers

Here is an image I tried to make to maybe explain what i am dealing with a bit more. The lines do have bends and curves. Hopefully, someone may know of a way to accomplish this and some code to get me in the right direction.

[image]

I

Comment: 3d buffer? Then 3d union. https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/3d-analyst-toolbox/buffer-3d.htm

Comment: I don't believe that will work, it only accepts a single distance for the buffer, whereas I have one distance in the Z direction and another in the XY